# Model binding fails from form on Razor Page using Tag Helpers

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a model "behind" my page with a property that's a model of my search form. My form was working fine and then suddenly all the properties stopped binding and my Post action handler saw the search form model has having loads of `null`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Tag Helpers for a form and add input controls you can add your own `name="myProperty"` to each, or you can omit this and this attribute is auto-generated.

Imagine you have 10 inputs and you add a new one but forget to add a `name` attribute on this recent one, then the helper adds its own like "SearchForm.MyProperty".

The previous 10 end up with `name="myProperty"` but the last one is `name="SearchForm.MyProperty"`.

In this situation model binding fails, *presumably* because these paths are mixed and the one matching `SearchForm.MyProperty` is more specific, making the others look like they should bind to properties on the page model.

Presumably when your supply your own names and they are all lacking the `SearchForm.` prefix then its smart enough to figure out to bind them all to `SearchForm`.

Fix could be not to supply your own `name` attributes to the inputs at all.

An improvement to Razor binding (to remove the surprise here) might be to always fail unless the names are prefixed accurately, though this would break existing code.